# Is it possible to access pre-set textureunits within a shader?

Tags: shader, webgl

**TL;DR:** I've activated and bound textures to textureunits 1-4 and now I wish to use them within shaders without using a program specific uniform position. Is it possible to read data from textures using the "global" texture units?

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding how to access textures in webgl. Here in [this tutorial on textures](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-texture-units.html) it says "*Texture units are a global array of references to textures.*", and this sounds great. I've bound my textures using

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1 + i);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
```

where `i` is the index of the newly created texture and `tex` is the texture itself.

But it doesn't give an example of how to access the texture within a shader using this global reference. In [this tutorial from the same page](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2-textures.html) it does give an example of how to access the textures from within a shader, but only when using an uniform position (much like how an attribute is accessed), which requires a program (and thus, removing the global aspect, in a way, since it's dependent on the program to be accessed). In [this preceding tutorial](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html) any details of how to actually set up the texture "u_texture" is skipped altogether.

In short, I have two programs, and I wish to use textures globally in both of them without having to getUniformLocation on each program, if it's possible to do so. Seeing the promises of texture units, I thought I could use them, but I don't know how to actually do something like

```
sampler2D textureUnit2;
```

within the shaders. Is this possible? Am i confusing the implementation of the textureUnits with the practicality of using them?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to use textures globally in both of them without having to getUniformLocation on each program, if it's possible to do so

It is **not** possible to do so.

The texture units are global. You can think of it just like a global array in JavaScript

```
const textureUnits = [
  { TEXTURE_2D: someTexture, },       // unit 0
  { TEXTURE_2D: someOtherTexture, },  // unit 1
  { TEXTURE_2D: yetAnotherTexture, }, // unit 2
  ...
];
```

You can bind a texture to a texture unit by first calling `gl.activeTexture` and then calling `gl.bindTexture`. Example:

```
const unit = 2;
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, yetAnotherTexture);
```

`yetAnotherTexture` is now bound to texture unit 2

Separately you have shader programs. To access a texture you declare a `uniform sampler2d someName;` in your shader.

```
uniform sampler2D foobar;
```

Think of that as an index into the texture units. You then need to set the index (tell the shader program which global texture unit to use)

```
const foobarLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(someProgram, "foobar");
...
// tell the program to use the texture on unit 2
const indexOfTextureUnit = 2;
gl.uniform1i(foobarLocation, indexOfTextureUnit);
```

The texture units themselves are global. The uniforms of a program are unique to each program. You need to set them to tell them which texture unit you want that uniform to reference. Uniforms default to 0 so if you want them to reference texture unit 0 then you don't need to set them but for any other texture unit you do need to set them.

Imagine GLSL's `texture2D` function was written in JavaScript. It would work something like

```
function texture2d(sampler, texcoord) {
  const texture = textureUnits[sampler].TEXTURE_2D;
  return getColorFromTextureAtTexcoord(texture, texcoord);
}
```

So if I did this

```
uniform sampler2D foobar;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(foobar, v_texcoord);
}
```

Then I set the `foobar` uniform to 2

```
const foobarLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(someProgram, "foobar");
...
// tell the program to use the texture on unit 2
const indexOfTextureUnit = 2;
gl.uniform1i(foobarLocation, indexOfTextureUnit);
```

It's going to reference the global texture unit at index 2.

Note: This code in your question

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1 + i);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
```

seems wrong. It should use `TEXTURE0` as a base, not `TEXTURE1`

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + i);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
```

[This diagram](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html) might help visualize how it works

[image]

Above you can see shader program (gold) has two uniforms `decal` and `diffuse`.

- `decal` is set to 3 so it's referencing texture unit 3. texture unit 3 is bound to the `decalTexture` (an image of a F)
- `diffuse` is set to 6 so it's referencing texture unit 6. texture unit 3 is bound to the `diffuseTexture` (a 4x4 checkerboard)

Note that texture unit 0 is also bound to the `decalTexture` but the shader program is not referencing texture unit 0 so at least for the purpose of drawing pixels, in other words executing the shader program, texture unit 0 is not being used.

Comment: Wow, many thanks! The shader community sure is the absolute best when it comes to receiving help.